# How/Can I join multiple pages together through github?

Tags: html, css, github

I've built different pages on Github for my website including different screens such as loading screens etc. How can I put all these together to create the final website, if I can?

If it's not possible, could someone please suggest an alternate way?

Thanks,
Majh

Comment: Can you be more specific? Do you mean that you have your website in a a repository and you want to make it live via GitHub Pages?

Comment: can you add more point on your question??